# .aspx page dedicated to respond to ajax requests, how to set content type

Tags: asp.net, ajax, content-type

I am creating a .aspx page to respond to ajax requests.

If I return json back, how do I set the content type so my calling page receives the JSON properly?

I'm using jquery if that matters.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest against using an ASPX page that way.

An ASMX web service or even ASHX HttpHandler would be better.  When you make a call to an ASPX page, the Page class must be instantiated even if you're just using Response.Write() to output JSON.  It's a lot of unnecessary overhead to add to what should be a lightweight call.

Comment: These are much better approaches than an ASPX page.  They sidestep the whole page model and result in snappier code.

Answer (score 0):

Response.ContentType = "application/json"

Answer (score 0):

Response.ContentType = "application/text"